# Determine all points of finite order of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is problem $2.12(e)$ from Silverman Tate. I am trying everything I can think of and thus far my progress, if it is that, has led me to a pretty cool problem, but I feel like I am doing this incorrectly.

Find all the finite order points of $$y^2-y=x^3-x$$ I found a transformation that turns the curve into $$y^2=x^3-432x+15120$$

The determinant of this implies that potential finite order points might be in the set

$$y \in \{2^i\times3^j;0\le i\le 4,0\le j\le6\}$$

But checking this has turned into a problem that requires computation they probably didn't have readily available in the $60s$, so I feel like I'm way off the mark. I am really new to this so please take it easy :).

Comment: The torsion points form a group so if, for example, there is a point of order $6$, there is also a point of order $3$ and a point of order $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to see it is that the curve $$y^2 - y = x^3 - x$$ has $5$ solutions mod $2$ i.e. $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),\infty$ and $7$ solutions mod $3$, i.e. $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),\infty$

so the torsion subgroup of $E$ injects into both $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ and so it is trivial.

Comment: Maybe you want to remark that it has good reduction at both $2$ and $3$?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned I am using the Nagell-Lutz theorem as it is phrased in Husemöller's Elliptic Curves (thrm 5.5.1) and that is valid for primes with good reduction.